# Разбить строку на JSON

Tags: php, массивы, json, строки

У меня имеется строка следующего жуткого вида:

```
 button_id798_number=798&button_id798_size=936&button_id798_price=0&button_id798_status=2&button_id799_number=799&button_id799_size=840&button_id799_price=0&button_id799_status=2&button_id800_number=800&button_id800_size=840&button_id800_price=329280&button_id800.......
```

Это кусочек, в таком виде хранится множество значений по разным участкам карты домов. Как наиболее корректно её разбить на json массив следующего типа:

```
{
"1": {
     "point_number":"1",
     "point_size":"819",
     "point_price":"491400",
     "point_status":"0"
     }
...
}
```

Никак не придумаю наиболее безболезненный и простой вариант.  Пробовал манипуляции с `explode`, неужели остаётся по сотне раз профильтровать строку,чтобы избавиться от всего лишнего, разбить её на чистенький массив и воспользоваться `json_encode`? Может быть есть ещё какие-то варианты?..

Answer (score 1):

Если ничего не путаю, то это т.н. query string, а значит

```
parse_str($str, $output);
$json = json_encode($output);
```

справится с вашей задачей

Comment: хм.. однако!) меня в огромной строке смутило, что id везде меняется.  достаточно просто загнать в цикл, где динамически добавлять в конец button_id нужный номер?))

Answer (score 1):

Можно прогнать через регулярное выражение и сделать сразу нужный массив еще в строке запроса, а потом разобрать строку как рекомендует VladimirAbramov

```
<?php
$query1 = 'button_id798_number=798&button_id798_size=936&button_id798_price=0&button_id798_status=2&button_id799_number=799&button_id799_size=840&button_id799_price=0&button_id799_status=2&button_id800_number=800&button_id800_size=840&button_id800_price=329280';

$query2 = preg_replace('/_id(\d+)_(.+?)=/', '[$1][point_$2]=', $query1);
parse_str($query2, $out); // better to be safe than sorry
print '<pre>' ;
var_dump($query2, $out['button']);
```

[Результат в песочнице](http://3v4l.org/n2d6f)

Answer (score -1):

Ответ был дан [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5397726/parse-query-string-into-an-array). Используйте `parse_str`

```
<?
$get_string = "button_id798_number=798&button_id798_size=936&...";
parse_str($get_string, $get_array);
$json = json_encode($get_array);
print_r($json);
```

Answer (score -1):

Похожий вариант на уже приведенное здесь решение
- недостаток: более громоздкое решение (parse_str реализована в ручную)
+ преимущество: возможность обработки данных (ключей и значений) до преобразования в json

```
<?php
    $q_str = "button_id798_number=798&button_id798_size=936&button_id798_price=0&button_id798_status=2&button_id799_number=799&button_id799_size=840&button_id799_price=0&button_id799_status=2&button_id800_number=800&button_id800_size=840&button_id800_price=329280";

   $q_tmp = explode("&", $q_str); $q = array();
   foreach($q_tmp as $p){$p=explode("=", $p); $q[$p[0]]=$p[1];}
   $j = json_encode ($q);
   echo $j;
?>
```

Еще вариант, без использования json_encode (т.к. она не поддерживается в версиях языка до 5.2, если не ошибаюсь)

```
<?php
    $q_str = "button_id798_number=798&button_id798_size=936&button_id798_price=0&button_id798_status=2&button_id799_number=799&button_id799_size=840&button_id799_price=0&button_id799_status=2&button_id800_number=800&button_id800_size=840&button_id800_price=329280";

   $q_tmp = explode("&", $q_str); $q = array();
   foreach($q_tmp as $p){$p=explode("=", $p); $q[]= "\"{$p[0]}\" : \"{$p[1]}\"";}
   $j = "{\n".implode(",\n", $q)."\n}";
   echo $j;
?>
```

Преимущество и недостаток тотже) Так же, эти варианты можно и слить в один, если кому-то понадобится и json-строка и php массив, а для особо хардкорных любителей "стоя в гамаке" в том же цикле можно эмулировать и сам implode :D

```
<?php
   $q_tmp = explode("&", $q_str); $j=""; $c = count($q_tmp)-1;
   for($i=0; $i<=$c; $i++){$p=explode("=", $q_tmp[$i]); $j.= '"'.$p[0].'" : "'.$p[1].($i<$c ? "\",\n" : "\"");}
   $j = "{\n".$j."\n}";
   echo $j;
?>
```

*В последнем случае, чтобы в json не попала какая-нибудь бяка, типак " там где они не нужны, можно использовать вот такую функцию для очистки

```
function cleanStr($s="", $tag=true, $quot='\"'){

 return ((is_string($s)) ? (str_replace(array("\r\n", "  ", '"'), array(" ", " ", $quot), ($tag==true ? $s : strip_tags($s)))) : $s);

 }
```

т.е. будет как-то так

```
 [...] '" : "'.cleanStr($p[1]).($i<$c ? "\",\n" : "\"");
```

Но это все для тех, кто любит различными способами извращаться и изобретать заново уже существующие функции php (эдак можно и explode циклом реализовать, к стати, тоже) =D

UPD: А для реализации вложенности можно запихнуть все это в функцию, с вызовом самой себя в случае необходимости, например так:

```
<?php

 function toJSON($str){
   if(strripos ($str, "&")===false && strripos ($str, "=")===false){return $str;} //Если это было уже готовое значение - просто вернуть его
    $q_tmp = explode("&", $str); 
   $q = array();
   foreach($q_tmp as $p){$p=explode("=", $p); $q[$p[0]]=toJSON($p[1]);} 
   return json_encode ($q);
 }
 $j = toJSON($q_str);
?>
```